# How to show cursor at particular position in Primeng's p-editor

Tags: typescript, primeng, angular7

I am using primeng p-editor in angular 7,Unable to set cursor position at particular position By default it is showing at starting position only.

I'm using p-editor in the following way:

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="remarks" [style]="{'height':'10rem'}">
 <p-header>
  <span class="ql-formats">
    <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
    <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
    <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
  </span>
 </p-header>
</p-editor>
```

Please provide any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best way to do this is in your component code, either in your `ngAfterViewInit()` method or wherever it is in your workflow that you want to set the cursor position.

You need to get the default quill instance from the Editor component and then set the selection (with a length of zero) to set the cursor position:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Editor } from "primeng/primeng";

@Component({
    selector: 'editor-demo',
    templateUrl: 'editor-demo.component.html'
})

export class EditorDemoComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(Editor) editor: Editor;
    remarks: string;

    constructor() {
        this.remarks = '<div>Hello World!</div><div>PrimeNG <b>Editor</b> Rocks</div><div><br></div>';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // this hook gets called after the view has been fully initialized, and
        // should set the cursor position immediately before the word 'World'
        this.editor.getQuill().setSelection(6);
    }
}
```

You can find the Quill Editor API documentation for the setSelection() method here: https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setselection